# Searching values from 0 to 1 java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing, integer

I am trying to solve a puzzle by taking following coordinates from a file and finding the way from 0 to 1 by putting these into ArrayList and then starting from int 0 and finding whats it connect with and going to 1.

```
11 3
2 3
0 3
1 4
5 4
5 7
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
0 5
```

I have done so far is fetching values from file and putting it into ArrayList,

```
ArrayList<String[]> listValues = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ArrayList<String> resultSet= new ArrayList<String>();
try{  

    String line = null;
    String fileName =("C:\\Users\\Kamran Ali\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TestMazeDone\\maze1.txt");
    System.out.println("File:  " +fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null)
    {
        String[] locations = line.split(" ");
        listValues.add(locations);
    }  
    br.close();

}
//Handling File not found or Path Error Exceptions
catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    System.out.println("Specified file does'nt exist");
}
//Handling Input/Output Exceptions
catch(IOException ex){
    System.out.println("There was an error, please try again");
}
```

I am not having any clue how to do the rest, which is:

1. Find where is 0 int.
2. Find adjacent value of 0 int,
3. find adjacent value of that int, and put into an Array... and keep going until int 1.
4. Print out that array.

Output for above file should be like this: 
     `[0 5 4 1]`

Comment: Your question is not clear. And I don't see any tried from you to write this (only the parsing). Improve your example and see about some traversal algorithm to have some ideas.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But I am not that good with programing, so I am not having any idea about h/ow to compare and find next value to 0 in my arrayllist. maybe a for loop

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds of [Graph Traversal Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal). This kind of problem can be solved easily by graph traversal algorithm ([BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)).